# How to run a script on pressing a button python tkinter

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following code

```
import cv2 as cv #for displaying it's been used OpenCV
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt #for plotting
import os #for saving the data in folder
import numpy as np #for array-handling and plotting
import matplotlib
#importing from keras
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential, load_model
from keras.layers.core import Dropout, Activation
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.utils import np_utils
import tkinter
import h5py #for creation h5py data
matplotlib.use('agg')
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3' #keep keras backend tensorflow quiet


class epoch():
    # now we need to split MNIST data into training and testing data
    # MNIST contains 70,000 images of handwritten digits: 60,000 for
    # training and 10,000 for testing. The images are grayscale,
    # 28x28 pixels, and centered to reduce preprocessing and get started quicker.
    (X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

    # MNIST dataset contains only grayscale images
    # we can view them as follows using OpenCV
    # it needs to be uncommented
    # numpy_horizontal = np.hstack((X_train[1], X_train[2], X_train[3], X_train[4], X_train[5]))
    # cv.imshow("Image", numpy_horizontal)
    # cv.waitKey(0)

    # STEP2: Preprocessing the data
    # In order to see the shapes of downloaded data
    print("X_train shape", X_train.shape)
    print("y_train shape", y_train.shape)
    print("X_train shape", X_test.shape)
    print("y_test shape", y_test.shape)

    # In order to input, it's been reshaped the actual data
    X_train = X_train.reshape(60000, 784)
    X_test = X_test.reshape(10000, 784)
    # For convenience it's been converted the type of data from uint8 to float32
    X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
    X_test = X_test.astype('float32')
    # Again for the input, it's been normalized
    X_train /= 255
    X_test /= 255

    # Shape after two steps of reshape and normalization
    print("After preprocessing X_train shape is", X_train.shape)
    print("After preprocessing X_test shape is", X_test.shape)

    # To show the classes (labels) that are from 0 to 9
    # it's been used np.unique function, which returns
    # the stored uniques values (not all of the values within y_train)
    # and it's type as uint8 also if return_counts is True, specifies
    # the occurance of respective number in the array
    print(np.unique(y_train, return_counts=True))

    # Then it's been done one-shot-encoding becuase
    # the classes should have the same meaning for computer
    # not 0<1<2<3, thus y values will be encoded into the
    # vectors with the same meaning
    # the encoding has been done using keras' numpy-related utilities
    num_classes = 10
    print("Shape before OHE:", y_train.shape)
    Y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
    Y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)
    print("Shape after OHE:", Y_train.shape)

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(512, input_shape=(784,)))  # The input layer and the first hidden layer
    model.add(Activation('relu'))  # the fucntion used in first hidden layer
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))  # to avoid overfitting

    model.add(Dense(512))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    model.add(Dense(10))
    model.add(Activation('softmax'))

    # training the model and saving validation data in history
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'], optimizer='adam')

    history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train,
                        batch_size=128, epochs=10,
                        verbose=2,
                        validation_data=(X_test, Y_test))

    # saving the model
    # model_name = h5py.File('mnist.hdf5', 'w'
    save_dir = "/home/amanzhol/MNIST"
    model_name = 'models/keras_mnist.h5'
    model_path = os.path.join(save_dir, model_name)
    model.save(model_path)
    print('The model is saved at %s ' % model_path)

    # STEP5:The Evaluation of the Model
    mnist_model = load_model('models/cnn-mnist-new.h5')
    loss_and_metrics = mnist_model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, verbose=2)

    # Note about verbose
    # By setting verbose 0, 1 or 2 you just say how do you want to 'see' the training progress for each epoch.
    # verbose=0 will show you nothing (silent)
    # verbose=1 will show you an animated progress bar like this:
    # progres_bar
    # verbose=2 will just mention the number of epoch like this:
    # Epoch 1/70

    print("Test Loss", loss_and_metrics[0])
    print("Test Accuracy", loss_and_metrics[1])

    plt.figure(1)

    # summarize history for accuracy

    plt.subplot(211)
    plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'])
    plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'])
    plt.title('Model Accuracy')
    plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
    plt.xlabel('Epoch')
    plt.legend(['Training', 'Validation'], loc='lower right')

    # summarize history for loss

    plt.subplot(212)
    plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
    plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
    plt.title('Model Loss')
    plt.ylabel('Loss')
    plt.xlabel('Epoch')
    plt.legend(['Training', 'Validation'], loc='upper right')

    plt.tight_layout()

    plt.show()
```

I have my gui in which I want to click a button and then run this script that trains epochs in the console. The problem is that when I import it to my gui, it does it right away without my intervention, can I use any function that will make it run only after pressing a button?

Comment: Please try to reduce all of that code down to a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

make a variable that is equal to zero then when you press a button make the value 1. Then create a if statement saying if the variable is equal to 1 then run your code.

Comment: Honestly I'm not good with python, how could I set the button to 1?

Comment: not setting the button to 1 just create a variable and set the int value of the variable to zero and then 1 when you press the button